# Flash AS3 - Internal namespace modifier

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am working on a library that I wish to hide the internals of to the outside world.

I figured I can use 'internal class' where ever I wanted to hide the class,

How ever to my understanding, declaring a class in namespace test.NS1 means it can only
access classes defines in test.NS1 and nothing else.

For example,

(both in the same library)

```
/src/NS/test.as - internal class
/src/NS/test2/test2.as - internal class
```

test / test2 cannot see each other.
Am I missing something here? or is there no proper way to hide my internal classes yet let them talk within the library ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace "internal" restricts access to classes defined within the **same package**.  Therefore, a class `com.mycompany.app.Foo` can see the internal class `com.mycompany.app.Bar`, but not `com.mycompany.app.data.Baz`.

See http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/langref/statements.html#internal

Comment: Thanks for the response, Essentially it means I can not 'hide my classes' from outside while also building my package directories in a logical manner?

Comment: Not with the "internal" namespace, if you want it to apply to sub-packages.  An alternative would be to define your own custom namespace and use it for classes you want to be "hidden", similar to the as3_internal namespace.  Developers can still get at it if they really want to, but it won't be visible by default.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference.

Yes you can hide your classes with internal namespaces!
You can create a different namespace in each sub package, all pointing to the same URI.

for example:

com.mycompany.app
   internal namespace foo = "yourcompany.com/as3/namespaces/internal_yourcompany"

com.mycompany.app.data
   internal namespace foo_data = "yourcompany.com/as3/namespaces/internal_yourcompany"

foo and foo_data will be the same namespace, but in a different package.
I found this explanation [here](http://www.leichtgewicht.at/718/mastering-as3-namespaces/#basics)

> For the visibility of properties, all that matters is the uri. You can define two
>   namespaces with a different name in two different packages. As long as they contain the 
>   same uri, they will refer to the same property.

```
namespace aNs = "myUri";
namespace bNs = "myUri";

class MyClass {
  aNs var foo: String;
}

var instance: MyClass = new MyClass();
instance.aNs::foo; // works as expected
instance.bNs::foo; // works too

var cNs: Namespace = new Namespace( "myUri" );
instance.cNs::foo; // works as well
```